# Cutting a pandas DataFrame into small blocks and do simple calculations on each block

Tags: python, pandas

I want to divide pandas DataFrame columns into blocks of 3 and find the mean of each block for each row.

Towards that end, by using a for-loop, I created a list of DataFrames by cutting them into blocks of 3, found their mean and reshaped it back into the shape I want.

The following code does the job:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(2000,100))
blocks = [df.iloc[:,i:i+3] for i in range(0,df.shape[1],3)]

list_df = []    
for quarter in range(0,len(blocks)):
    list_df.append(blocks[quarter].T.mean())
df = np.reshape(list_df,(len(blocks),len(blocks[0]))).T
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

The problem is, this is incredibly slow (given the size of my data, the for-loop is really taking its time). My question is, is there a more efficient way to do it? Specifically, are there any built-in pandas functions that do the same job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it directly by specifying axis=1 in `mean` on the selection of the 3 columns in the list comprehension. then use it in `pd.concat`

```
df_ = pd.concat([df.iloc[:,i:i+3].mean(axis=1) for i in range(0,df.shape[1],3)], 
                axis=1, ignore_index=True)
```

**In the specific case where the number of columns is a multiple of 3** (not like in your example but just in case for your real data), you could use `to_numpy`, `reshape` and `mean` along the last axis, it should even be faster.

```
pd.DataFrame(df.to_numpy()
               .reshape(df.shape[0], df.shape[1]//3, 3)
               .mean(axis=-1)
            )
```

Comment: Oh wow, didn't realize there was such an elegant solution available. I'm really new to this and it actually took me a while to realize that I should do a list comprehension. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

First, I assume your index is the usual `0, 1, ...` Then, simply

```
df.groupby(df.index//3).mean()
```

should do the trick.

Comment: this is a really good idea, but the OP wants to group over columns, not index, so I think `df.groupby(np.arange(df.shape[1])//3, axis=1).mean()` would be more what needed :)